# How to add null value in Azure Datafactory Derived columns expression builder

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am currently using Azure Datafactory in that I am creating a Derived column and since the field will always will be blank, so I want the value to be NULL

currently Derived Column I am doing this for adding the expression e.g. toString("null") and toString(null()) but this is appearing as string. I only want null to appear without quotes in Json document

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and got below results.

I tried to give `null()` to a column and it gave the error like below.

[image]

So, in ADF Dataflow, there should be any wrap over `null()` with the functions like **toInteger()** or **toString()**

When I give `toString(null())` when **id is 4** in derived column of dataflow and the **sink is a JSON**, it gave me the below output.

[image]

**You can see the row with **`id==4`** skipped the null valued key in JSON.** If you give `toString(null())` same key in every row will be skipped.

You can go through [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/469915/mapping-data-flow-null-value-issue-in-json-which-r) by @[ShaikMaheer-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/na/?userid=025a0b1b-b2ce-4dec-bd9b-0c3db34a196d) to understand more about this.

**AFAIK**, The workaround for this can be to store the null as `'null'` string to get that key in JSON like this and later use this as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but I have already tried above things and getting similar results. Now we have decided to handle default values in .Net Class property